# How to avoid reloading table data when browser is refreshed in Angular (Spring API)

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, api

I'm developing a web application which gets the data from backend via spring rest api and when the browser is refreshed the data is duplicated into the table.

**Spring API**

```
@GetMapping("/members/first")
public ArrayList<Member> getFirst(){
    ArrayList<Member> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    firstList .clear();

    arrayList.addAll(repository.findAll());
    for (Member m : arrayList){
       if (m instanceof First) {
                firstList.add(m);
       }
  }
    return firstList;
}
```

According to my code **Member** is the super class and **First** is a child class. So I get the list of data relevant to **First** class only.
But when the browser refreshed the same datais added again.
How to stop that ?

**Angular Component**

```
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

members: Member[];

constructor(
   private httpClientService: HttpClientService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.httpClientService.getFirst().subscribe(
       response => {this.members = response;
       });
}
}
```

**Http Service**

```
getFirst(){
   return this.httpClient.get<Member[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/members/first');
}
```

As the below diagram shows when the browser is refreshed every time the data is duplicated and entered to the table.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First ensure your get API will get same results with multiple calls, from the the code you pasted, it seems neither **firstList** nor **arrayList** is a local variable.
It should be an issue. Since we are not understand the meaning of ArrayList, i'm not sure if it should be reset to empty. At least firstList should be reset to empty on entry.

Seconde, you forget to un-subscribe the subscriber, not sure if it is the cause of the issue, but it's an issue apparently.

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

```
members: Member[];

private subscription = new Subscription();

constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription.add(this.httpClientService.getFirst().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.members = response;
        }));
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```